# Count unique records in 2 tables

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables that contain data from different temperature sensors:
Table1
_TimeStamp Temperature
2009-12-20 11:59:56.2  10.1
2009-12-20 11:59:56.3  10.2
2009-12-20 11:59:56.4  11.0
2009-12-20 11:59:56.5  Null

Table2
_TimeStamp Temperature
2009-12-20 11:59:56.2  10.5
2009-12-20 11:59:56.5  9.8
2009-12-20 11:59:56.7  12.0
2009-12-20 11:59:56.9  10.0

I want to count the number of records for which either one of the two temperature sensors made a non-null measurement.  For the example above, the count is 6, though there are actually 864000 or so records in each table.
I know the following SQL Server query is wrong, but could you help correct it?

```
(SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(_TimeStamp) FROM Table1) UNION  (SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(_TimeStamp) FROM Table2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to union first, then get the count.

```
select count(ts) from
(
 select _timestamp as ts
 from table1
 where temperature is not null
 union  
 select _timestamp 
 from table2
 where temperature is not null
)innerSql
```

Comment: Union is not necessary to accomplish the task he's working on...in fact, it will add extra CPU time to the execution plan.

Comment: @Ed Altorfer are you sure? because he wants to combine the data from both tables first, and then exclude any duplicates, and then take the count.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at this

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE(
        _TimeStamp DATETIME,
        Temperature FLOAT
)

DECLARE @Table2 TABLE(
        _TimeStamp DATETIME,
        Temperature FLOAT
)

INSERT INTO @Table1 SELECT '2009-12-20 11:59:56.2',10.1  
INSERT INTO @Table1 SELECT '2009-12-20 11:59:56.3',10.2  
INSERT INTO @Table1 SELECT '2009-12-20 11:59:56.4',11.0  
INSERT INTO @Table1 SELECT '2009-12-20 11:59:56.5',Null  


INSERT INTO @Table2 SELECT '2009-12-20 11:59:56.2',10.5  
INSERT INTO @Table2 SELECT '2009-12-20 11:59:56.5',9.8  
INSERT INTO @Table2 SELECT '2009-12-20 11:59:56.7',12.0  
INSERT INTO @Table2 SELECT '2009-12-20 11:59:56.9',10.0  

SELECT COUNT(1) TOTAL
FROM    (
            SELECT _TimeStamp FROM @Table1 WHERE Temperature IS NOT NULL
            UNION
            SELECT _TimeStamp FROM @Table2 WHERE Temperature IS NOT NULL
        ) sub
```

By using a **UNION** and not a **UNION ALL**, you will get the **DISTINCT**  time stamps.

Comment: Nice trick with leaving out the distinct clause. Though the question's body doesn't mention unique records, it's good to know.

Comment: As I mentioned to someone else, it is not necessary to use union here. It adds cost to the execution plan. Why not just use the + operator?

Comment: **@Allain Lalonde,@Ed Altorfer** , it does not mention UNIQUE records, but it does mention a count of 6, which from the data, would give 7, unless unique is used. *For the example above, the count is 6*

Answer (score 0):

where does the count of 6 come from your data?
also what is wrong with your query?
seems fine to me. you just have to remove the () around selects and name the columns.

Comment: These are the 6 times when at least one of the two tables had a non-null entry in the Temperature column.  Sorry to not have explained more clearly.     
2009-12-20 11:59:56.2   
2009-12-20 11:59:56.3   
2009-12-20 11:59:56.4   
2009-12-20 11:59:56.5   
2009-12-20 11:59:56.7   
2009-12-20 11:59:56.9

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to try something like this.

```
SELECT
(
   (SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(Id) FROM [Table]) +
   (SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(Id) FROM [Table2])
)
```

This will give you the sum of the counts from both tables. You can change the subqueries to exhibit whatever conditions you want.